# Use awk to print variables and static text

Tags: awk

I have a text file containing two values per line separated by a space.  Field 1 is a URI and field 2 is a full URL.

My account doesn't have enough reputation to post links so please ignore the space after http in each of the examples.

Here's an example:

> /uri1 http ://www.example. com/uri1
> /uri2 http ://www.example.com/uri2
> /uri3/test http ://www.example.com/uri3/index.html
> /uri4?id=123 http ://www.example.com/uri4/page1.html

I'd like to create a new file where field 1 is the same, but I modify field 2 to be a combination of field2 with some static text then field 1.
Below is my example:

> /uri1 http ://www.example.abc/uri1/#/www.test.abc/uri1
> /uri2 http ://www.example.abc/uri2/#/www.test.abc/uri2
> /uri3/test http ://www.example.abc/uri3/index.html/#/www.test.abc/uri3/test
> /uri4?id=123 http ://www.example.abc/uri4/page1.html/#/www.test.abc/uri4?id=123

I thought awk would be the easiest way to do this, but it's not working like I expected.

Below is the command I'm trying to use, but it prints the fields over the top of each other and the output is like it's combined.

```
awk '{print $1, $2"/#/www.test.com"$1}' file.txt
```

Comment: After removing the excess spaces from the source file, your code works for me.  _"it prints the fields over the top of each other and the output is like it's combined."_ What does that mean?  What output do you actually get?

Comment: How do you mean "over the top of each other"? Does the input file have DOS line endings?

Comment: Ok, I was running my test to stdout on the screen.  Once I redirected it to a file and viewed it with vi I can see there were a bunch of ^M characters before the /#/.  That must've been causing the output on my screen to look broken like the lines were just stopping halfway through one value.